# Swift TextField を画面いっぱいに

Tags: swift

SwiftにてTextField を画面いっぱいに 広げ どこをタップしてもキーボードが立ち上がるようにすることは可能でしょうか ？

Comment: 質問の主旨がどこにあるのか？すなわち「TextField を画面いっぱいに 広げ」ることが主旨なのか、「どこをタップしてもキーボードが立ち上がるようにすること」が主旨なのか？前者なら、`UITextField`ではなく、`UITextView`の採用を検討してください、という回答になりますし、後者なら、画面タップでキーボードを表示→コードでテキストフィールドに、入力のフォーカスを当てる→`firstResponder`の処理をする方法という回答になります。どちらですか？それともそれら以外？

Comment: 後者です その場合どうしたらいいですか ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「どこをタップしてもキーボードが立ち上がるようにする」が、質問の主旨であるという前提で、回答をいたします。
「キーボードが立ち上がる」というアプリの挙動は、プログラマ側から見れば、**`UITextView`、`UITextField`などの、ユーザがテキスト入力を行うViewに、フォーカスが当たる**という表現になります。それをコードで表現すると、こうなります。仮に`UITextField`のインスタンス`textField`に入力のフォーカスを当てる場合、

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

とコードを書きます。
キーボードを閉じる時、入力のフォーカスが、`textField`にあるとすると、

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

と書くのは、よく知られたTipsですが、それと対をなすメソッドということができるでしょう。

さて、次に「どこをタップしても」の部分について考えてみようと思います。
これについては、**Responder Chain**という、UIKitに含まれる機能について、学習する必要があります。

[Article - Using Responders and the Responder Chain to Handle Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events)

（以下は、上のリンク先をひととおり目を通された前提で、話を進めます）
ユーザが起こしたタッチイベントが、Viewの間を次々に伝播していくのが、Responder Chainのメカニズムですが、iOSの場合、最初にユーザのタッチイベントを受け取った、ボタン、スイッチ、Text Fieldなどが、処理をしてしまうので、「イベントの伝播」が生じないケースがほとんどです。なので、Responder Chainをよく知らない、あるいはまったく知らない人が多いのは、しかたないかも知れませんが、今回のケースでは、大事なポイントです。
ユーザのタッチイベントは、それを受け取って、処理するViewがなければ、次々と伝播していって、`UIViewController`のサブクラスに到達します。これは、つまり`UIViewController`のサブクラスに、ユーザのタッチイベントを受け取って処理するメソッド（`func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)`など）を記述しておけば、画面上のどこをタップしても、そのメソッドが実行されるということでもあります。

以上、`becomeFirstResponder()`と、Responder Chainの二つを組み合わせます。

`UIViewController`のサブクラスに、次のコードを記述します。仮に`UITextField`のインスタンスを`textField`とすると、

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます 確認します

Comment: また TextView は 入力 可能 なのですか ？

Comment: おっしゃっている意図がわかりかねます。あまりに言葉が足りません。日頃から、「言葉を尽くす」練習をなさることを、お勧めします。